# Using a definition to create a string then using it in a different definition? (ruby, watir)

Tags: ruby, watir

I was wondering if anyone can help me store a string then use it else here in a different definition.

so lets say for example,

```
<html>
     <body>
          <div id="example">
               143453
          </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

How could I store the number 143453 as a string, so I can use it elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply ask for the text of the element and store it in a variable:

```
number = browser.div(:id, "example").text
```

Another way is to use an HTML parser, such as Nokogiri. If you do a lot of parsing, this may provide [extra speed](http://zeljkofilipin.com/watir-nokogiri/). Somewhere you'll need to `require 'nokogiri'` then you can do this:

```
number = Nokogiri::HTML(browser.html).at_css("div#example").text
```